# Python - WebDriverException issue on particular webpage

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to scrape employement offers on this very webpage using selenium : https://candidat.pole-emploi.fr/offres/emploi/horticulteur/s1m1 .

But it returns an issue. However, when I try with another page (such as https://www.youtube.com/ for example), it works fine and I can get the html normally.

So I don't understand why this particular webpage blocks the whole process.

Here's my code :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

site = 'https://candidat.pole-emploi.fr/offres/emploi/horticulteur/s1m1'

wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', options=options)
wd.get(site)
```

And here is the error message :

```
WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-d232051ff849> in <module>()
      1 wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', options=options)
----> 2 wd.get(site)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in get(self, url)
    428         Loads a web page in the current browser session.
    429         """
--> 430         self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
    431 
    432     @property

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    416         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    417         if response:
--> 418             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    419             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    420                 response.get('value', None))

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    241                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    242             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)  # type: ignore[call-arg]  # mypy is not smart enough here
--> 243         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    244 
    245     def _value_or_default(self, obj: Mapping[_KT, _VT], key: _KT, default: _VT) -> _VT:

WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
  (Session info: headless chrome=94.0.4606.71)
Stacktrace:
#0 0x563e4590b6e3 <unknown>
#1 0x563e4561c9f3 <unknown>
#2 0x563e45619be6 <unknown>
#3 0x563e4560c0a5 <unknown>
#4 0x563e4560cfd5 <unknown>
#5 0x563e4560c366 <unknown>
#6 0x563e4560b945 <unknown>
#7 0x563e4560a86c <unknown>
#8 0x563e4560ab21 <unknown>
#9 0x563e4561e50c <unknown>
#10 0x563e456840c3 <unknown>
#11 0x563e4566f212 <unknown>
#12 0x563e456839bc <unknown>
#13 0x563e4566f643 <unknown>
#14 0x563e456468ec <unknown>
#15 0x563e45647db5 <unknown>
#16 0x563e4592fa14 <unknown>
#17 0x563e4593f15d <unknown>
#18 0x563e4593ee7b <unknown>
#19 0x563e4593f7a2 <unknown>
#20 0x563e4597852b <unknown>
#21 0x563e4593fa01 <unknown>
#22 0x563e459248f1 <unknown>
#23 0x563e45948408 <unknown>
#24 0x563e4594859a <unknown>
#25 0x563e4596232f <unknown>
#26 0x7f08e1bb86db start_thread
```

Comment: I got the same error, then I checked in GUI mode.. it works in GUI mode. If headless is not that important to you, then you should give it a try with GUI mode.

Comment: Glad you made it work. But how am I supposed to switch to GUI mode exactly? I'm not used to that.

Comment: I commented this line `options.add_argument('--headless')`

Comment: I get an issue if I comment this line out. FYI I'm working in Google Colab

Comment: on Google colab you can not run in GUI mode. It has to be headless mode.

Comment: different pages has different methods to detect scripts/bots/hackers/spamers - so if code works on one page then it doesn't means that i has to run on another. First you should test code on your local computer because it  runs GUI/Windows so it can display browser. Colab runs on server which doesn't use GUI/Windows and even if it could run GUI/Windows then it would try to display on monitor directly connected to this server, not on your monitor.